# My table is coming above the title I want it to be

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

My code is something like this whereas the table is coming above the section "Work experience".

```
\section{Work experience}

\begin{table}

\caption{Research Experience}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{3cm}|l|p{3cm}|l|}

\hline

S. No. & Employer’s name & Post Held & Length of service (date) & Nature of work \\

\hline

 1 & Sardar Vallabhai National Institute of Technology & Research Associate & From--August 2013 To--Till Date & Research \\ 

 \hline

 2 & Sardar Vallabhai National Institute of Technology & --- & From--January 2012 To-July 2013 & Research \\

\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Comment: You don't HAVE to use table, especially if you want a tabular to show up at a particular location.  Use \captionof from the caption package if you want a caption.

Comment: As of now, this post is a duplicate of [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) However, as suggested, you don't need to use a `table` environment to insert a `tabular`. Since you're not using a `\caption`, you can do without the floating `table`. Could you please clarify that you're not interested in a caption?

Comment: i want to show a table about my timeline in research experience and i want a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not using a `\caption`, you can insert a `tabular` *without* using a `table` environment. Use

```
\section{Working experience}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{..}
    ...
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

If there is too much space between your use of `\section` and the `tabular`, then you can insert a negative `\vspace{<len>}`, or use the `\centering` declaration inside a group:

```
\section{Working experience}

{\centering
  \begin{tabular}{..}
    ...
  \end{tabular}\par
}
```